# Why do liquids move from an area of high temperature to low temperature on a flat metal plate?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Sample setup:

- 12" Flat metal plate
- ~2 cc Liquid (I've tested a few oils and water,
  separately)
- Heat source beneath the metal plate

Liquid is placed in the center of the plate and heat is applied beneath. As the plate warms the liquid will migrate away from the areas of higher temperature to the areas of lower temperature. This is observed to be according to the pattern of heat applied, i.e. if heated with a burner in a ring pattern the liquid may form a small mound in the center, conversely, when heated in the center the liquid will flow away toward the edges.

The metal plate is not machined perfectly flat, though I expect the variances are insignificant given the amount of observed movement in the liquid.

What causes this phenomenon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the variation of surface tension with temperature. Hot water, for example, exhibits lower surface tension than cold water and the water in the colder region will attract and "suck up" the water in the hot region.

This reduction in surface tension with temperature is the reason why hot water does a better job wetting out dirty clothes and getting them cleaner than washing them in cold water.

Comment: If one has done enough vapor deposition of different metals using a boat heater, it becomes obvious that not all metals have the same sign of variation with temperature. If I recall properly (it has been a while), aluminum in particular liked to make a nice compact molten blob at the center of the boat (highest temperature), pulling in molten material from further out.

Comment: were you a fab engineer in a previous lifetime?

Comment: For a bit in a real fab, longer in thin film processing for materials science. Part of my varied background...

Comment: I did mat.sci. at HP in the course of designing and manufacturing thermal inkjet printheads. It was a bloody battlefield...